# How to get a readable stack trace for a webpack production environment for a minified bundle with dev-tool set to source-map?

Tags: javascript, runtime-error, stack-trace

Is it possible to get a **readable** stack trace for a webpack **production** environment for a **minified** bundle with dev-tool set to **source-map**? I am running Typescript and react with a Webpack build. An example of an exception that is being thrown is shown in the listing below:

```sh
http://localhost:8080/vendors~course-list.3042c44300bc08021f63.bundle.js:2:6029
http://localhost:8080/vendors~course-list.3042c44300bc08021f63.bundle.js:2:5067

in w in b in withRouter(b) in e in e in Suspense in div in e in e in S
```

In the above stacktrace the following observations can be made with the devtool option set to *source-map*:

- names remain minimised, e.g. w, b and e.
- minimised error locations are reported, e.g. line number and column
  numbers.

Comment: Did you get it to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using this npm package and it works great :)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sourcemapped-stacktrace

Example:

```
    import * as sourceStackTrace from 'sourcemapped-stacktrace';
    ...

    const minifiedStack = new Error().stack;
    sourceStackTrace.mapStackTrace(minifiedStack, (stackTrace: string[]) => {
        // Do your thing here
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @Mick for response. Have just read message. Cheers, very helpful will have a look and investigate sourcemapped-stacktrace and see if I can get it to work :)

Comment: Thanks @mick, I have tried _sourcemapped-stacktrace_ library and have managed to get an unminified stack trace with line number and columns, which is great! This seems to work for Firefox, Chromium and Opera browsers. Have tried with Safari and it reports back the **minified** stack trace. I am using this in _componentDidCatch_ method of react and it is working great on the stack property of the Error object there. I need to debug why the same is not happening on the _React.ErrorInfo_. Going to investigate further. Thanks very much for your help, appreciated and accepting your answer :)

Comment: I'm glad it helped you @anon_dcs3spp :) I think you forgot to mark it is answered though.

Comment: Ooops! Sorry @mick..marking it now. Again, greatly appreciated :)